# FingerprintManagerCompat isHardwareDetected return false in targetAPI 25

Tags: android, fingerprint

Both method isHardwareDetected() and hasEnrolledFingerprints() always return false. I found that target API 24 works fine, so this is problem just for 25. I would like to use the latest API but it's not possible without working fingerprint.

Activity

```
    FingerprintManagerCompat from = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(getApplication());
    boolean hardwareDetected = from.isHardwareDetected();
    boolean b = from.hasEnrolledFingerprints();
```

app.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tkuhn.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37132365

Answer (score 7):

Use the best of `FingerprintManager` & `FingerprintManagerCompat`.

Use `FingerprintManagerCompat`'s ***isHardwareDetected*** for older devices and `FingerprintManager`'s ***isHardwareDetected*** for new devices.

```
private boolean isSensorAvialable() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppContext, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    AppContext.getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class).isHardwareDetected();
        } else {
            return FingerprintManagerCompat.from(AppContext).isHardwareDetected();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The issues with the newer support libraries come from the fact that they are now actively checking the devices system features to include `FEATURE_FINGERPRINT`. It seems like the affected devices do not have this feature specified in their configs even though they have a fingerprint sensor. That's a fault on the device manufacturers side.

This is the check in `FingerprintManagerCompat` that will return `false`

```
  if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)) {  /**/  }
```

You could try [Reprint](https://github.com/ajalt/reprint) or [RxFingerpring](https://github.com/Mauin/RxFingerprint) as alternative solutions.

Comment: Do you have a link which confirms that?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the latest AndroidX `FingerprintManagerCompat` where this issue is fixed:

> FingerprintManagerCompat#getFingerprintManagerOrNull on API level 23
>   should not check PackageManager ([b/124066957](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124066957))

- from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

The Google Issue Tracker ticket reported that the support lib had this check:

> `mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)`
>   which can return false, even if scanner exists and fingerprint is
>   configured, and FingerprintManager can be used for authentication.
>   ...
>   We need to update FingerprintManagerCompat which also checks PackageManager. On API23 this flag doesn't exist

Which is what they did in `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-rc02`.

Comment: FYI. FingerprintManagerCompat is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

```
FingerprintManager manager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isHardwareDetected()) {
            //code here
        }
```

hope this help

Comment: I have to use FingerprintManagerCompat because minSdkVersion = 15.

Comment: You can check. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {}`