# PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT always returns false on API 23

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric

I am using Fingerprint authentication in my app. To decide whether a device has a fingerprint hardware or not I am using this

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT);
```

in the official document it is mentioned that it was added in API 23.

### What is working

This API is working fine for all the API 24 and above. (I have tested on 24, 26 and 30)

### What is not working

It returns false always even the device has fingerprint hardware available.

My questions are

- It it a bug?
- Am I missing something? Does my understanding of hasSystemFeature() is incorrect ?
- What is a more reliable way to check ?

I found a very interesting answer here which says that it can return false even [if device has fingerprint hardware because the feature may not be specified in config file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575967/fingerprintmanagercompat-ishardwaredetected-return-false-in-targetapi-25/44416381#44416381)  I don't know how credible that it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Biometric Library,
for java is **androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha04** and for kotlin is **androidx.biometric:biometric-ktx:1.2.0-alpha04**

in java

```
int canAuthenticate = BiometricManager.from(context).canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG);
if(canAuthenticate == BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE) {
   //The device has no fingerprint sensot
} else {
   //do some stuff work here
}
```

in kotlin

```
val canAuthenticate = BiometricManager.from(context).canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
if(canAuthenticate == BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE) {
   //The device has no fingerprint sensot
} else {
   //do some stuff work here
}
```

Comment: 2 reasons I would not use that. 1) FingerprintManager is deprecated. 2) FingerprintManager is returning null if the device only has FaceID authentication (In  Pixel 4)

Comment: I Update my answer, please check it, I hope it can help you